# Spinner doesn't refresh the fragment after changing the application language

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I'm internationalizing my application and my settings fragment (the responsible of the languages options) isn't working as I want.

It have an spinner with 3 languages and after selecting one of these it changes the language of the application. It works... if i selected Spanish and I return to the menu I see all in Spanish, and the same with other languages, but... the settings fragment doesn't refresh after selecting a language and I think that it's important. (The language of the settings screen doesn't change after selecting a language, it needs to change the fragment).

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Code:

```
    this.languagesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new              
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(@NonNull final AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   @NonNull final View view,
                                   int position,
                                   long id) {
            final String newLanguage;
            switch (languagesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                case "English":
                    newLanguage = "en";
                    break;
                case "Spanish":
                    newLanguage = "es";
                    break;
                default:
                    newLanguage = "ca";
                    break;
            }
            final Locale newLocal = new Locale(newLanguage);
            Locale.setDefault(newLocal);
            final Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
            newConfig.locale = newLocal;
            getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(@NonNull final AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Log.i("SettingsFragment", "Spinner is empty");
        }
    });
```

Comment: notify your spinner adapter for data set changes like adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh/recreate the ParentActivity to reflect the changes. You can call this method:

```
public static void refreshParentActivity(Context context) {
        Activity parentActivity = (Activity) context;
        Intent intent = parentActivity.getIntent();
        parentActivity.finish();
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```